# Android change from picking resource mdpi to xxhdpi

Tags: android

My device configuration is MDPI, but when it's in landscape mode and width is at least 600dp, I want to load different image size. Here's my resource configuration:

```
--res
  --drawable-hdpi
  --drawable-mdpi
  --drawable-w600dp-hdpi
  --drawable-w600dp-mdpi
  --drawable-w600dp-xhdpi
  --drawable-w600dp-xxhdpi
  --drawable-xhdpi
  --drawable-xxhdpi
```

When the device is in portrait mode, the drawables loaded are from the folder `drawable-mdpi` but when it's in landscape mode, it loads drawables from `drawable-w600dp-xxhdpi`. So I'm a little confused here. Shouldn't it load from `drawable-w600dp-mdpi`?

Comment: NO. w600dp indicates a device which minimum width (in portrait) is 600dp. then it's likely to be xhdpi or higher. Use `drawable-mdpi-land`, instead

Comment: but, I've seen people use `drawable-wxxxdp-mdpi` like that..

My problem is, I want to load bigger image size when the device is w600dp or higher, how do I do this?

Comment: That's for use with tablets.

Comment: Oh my gods.. yes you are right. I know that..
(sometimes my brain is suddenly miswired)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein does qualifier like `drawable-large-hdpi` for large device and high density really work? Because [Dianne Hackborn says "density goes with drawables, screen size goes with layouts.  If you are doing screen size with drawables or density with layouts, it is 99% likely you are doing something wrong."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_qdvw0ofiJk)

Comment: I always thought that large/small/xlarge/... were alternatives do (xy)dpi.

Comment: Right.. so the existence of `drawable-large-hdpi` in some projects really confuses me

Comment: I'm quite confused about large/... qualifiers that's why I really prefer (xy)dpi ones.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like drawable-wXXXXXdp-xxhdpi is broken, just another 'gift' from "google drawable buglopers". I bet they don't even write unit tests.

Solution:

Rename drawable to look like mydrawable_w600dp.png and put in into normal drawable-xxx folders.

Then create a duplicate layout for w600dp that will reference that mydrawable_w600dp. Use << include layout...>> if your layout is big and you don't want to maintain separate copies of them for different screen sizes.

It worked for me.